# Check if a value exists multidimensional array and return its key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array, say

```
$updates = array();
$updates['U1'] = array('F1', 'F2', 'F5');
$updates['U2'] = array('F3');
$updates['U3'] = array('F3', 'F4');
```

I need search for a value say `F5` so it should return the key `U1`.

And also if there is multiple occurrence of a value, should return the last key.

Eg. searching `F3` should return `U3` and not `U2`.

I have searched a lot and can't find a way. I am looking for a solution without using loops.

Comment: Loop through each entry in `$updates`, if the *value* contains the searched-for string, use *its key* as the result you're looking for…

Answer (score 0):

without using loop:

```
function findArrVal($arr = [], $param){
        static $indx = 0;
        if($indx == 0){
            krsort($arr);
        }
        
        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        $values = array_values($arr);
        
        if( count($values) == $indx ){
            return false;
        } else if( is_array($values[$indx]) && in_array($param, $values[$indx])){
            return $keys[$indx];
        } else {
            ++$indx;
            return findArrVal($arr, $param);
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

using loop:

```
function findArrVal($arr = [], $param){
        krsort($arr);
        foreach($arr as $key => $ar){
           if(is_array($ar) && in_array($param, $ar)){
               return $key;
           } 
        }
        return FALSE;
}
    
findArrVal($updates,'F3');
```

1. krsort - sorts the array in reverse order. ( to find the value at first occurrence )
2. is_array to check if the child value is an array type.
3. in_array to find the item on the child array.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe It's helpful for you.

```
function _getFindArrayKey(array $arr, $key)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        return true;
    }
    // check arrays contained in this array
    foreach ($arr as $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
            if (_getFindArrayKey($element, $key)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).